# comparison of the list in the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of lists:

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>()
{
    new Product()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Model = "Phone",
        TypeProd = new CheckTypes
        { 
            ChTypes = new List<CHType>
            { 
                new CHType
                { 
                    Id =  8, 
                    IdName = "261"
                }, 
                new CHType 
                {
                    Id = 9 , 
                    IdName = "149" 
                } 
            }
         }
    },
    new Product
    {
        Id = 1,
        Model = "Printer",
        TypeProd = new CheckTypes 
        { 
            ChTypes = new List<CHType> 
            { 
                new CHType 
                { 
                    Id =  8, 
                    IdName = null
                }, 
                new CHType 
                {
                    Id = 8, 
                    IdName = "261" 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

And I want to get the first item of this list by comparing the `IdName` elements with a `string[]`:

```
string[] arrStr = new string[] { "261", "149" };
```

How can I do this better? Tried using **foreach** and by creating a temporary object that takes an array value and then uses **intersect** to compare.

Comment: Could you please provide full example of your algorithm?

Comment: Make your arrStr as HashSet<string>. It will allow you to do fast lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it pretty simply with LINQ:

```
var product = productList
    .FindAll(x => x.TypeProd.ChTypes
                     .All(y => arrString.Contains(y.IdName));
```

This will give you all products whose `TypeProd.ChTypes` elements are all in `arrString`.
For faster performance, you may want to turn `arrString` into a `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: Good example. But you return the first element, I probably did not put it right, but I want to get the first element in this example, but there can be more elements. I want to find all the elements that contain the values ​​of the array.

Comment: For that, you can just change `FirstOrDefault` to `Where(...).ToList()`

Comment: You mean IdName = "261"  261

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, thanks! `var te = productList.FindAll(f => f.TypeProd.ChTypes.All(a => arrStr.Contains(a.IdName)));`

Comment: Something I did not think right away that you can sort through the elements of the array, not the collections, thank you for indicating the right path. :) And how do I make my second element also fit into the sample, because it contains "261"?

Comment: @Tibomso For that you would change `All` (all elements) to `Any` (any element). For this case, the result will be the same as the original list.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, thanks again! I'll go into details about these methods!